# anchor link is not working when adding and removing class in li

Tags: jquery, html

when i am adding active class to li it working properly but not working link when add or remove class in li. when click on anchor tag not redirect any location.

this is html code

```
<ul id="navig">
  <li class="one active"><a href="one">One</a></li>
  <li class="two"><a href="two">Two</a></li>
  <li class="three mobileonly"><a href="#">Three</a>
  <ul>
  <li class="one"><a href="one">One</a></li>
  <li class="two"><a href="two">Two</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

this is my jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#navig li').click(function(){     
    $('li').removeClass('active');
    $('li ul li').removeClass('active');

    $(this).addClass('active');
    $("li.mobileonly").removeClass('active');
});


  $('#navig li').hover(

    function() {
      //show its submenu
      $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(100);
    },
    function() {
      //hide its submenu
      $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(100);
    }
  );

});
```

Comment: Is it not working with this code?

Comment: it is working. this is adding and removing class properly but not working anchor link

Comment: Did you try to change selectors?

Comment: Please, post the changed code which has problem.

Comment: actully  li ul li  anchor are working good but  main ul li link not working

Comment: Everything you're doing here is completely doable with CSS, any reason for using JS instead?

Comment: could you please explain how we can add the class when click on li anchor by css

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying this? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5oj5au9/)

```
         $(document).on("click","#navig li a",function(){     
                $('li').removeClass('active');
                $('li ul li').removeClass('active');

                $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                $("li.mobileonly").removeClass('active');
            });

            $(document).ready(function() {
              $('#navig li').hover(

                function() {
                  //show its submenu
                  $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(100);
                },
                function() {
                  //hide its submenu
                  $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(100);
                }
              );

            });
```

Comment: i use this code by this any anchor link not working!

Comment: Isn't working fine in fiddle?. I used # for anchor tag. Please replace.

Comment: active class also adding by top code  but link not working

Comment: can you make a fiddle? and explain brief?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a valid href value, not just a random text string.

```
<ul id="navig">
    <li class="one active">
        <a href="#one">One</a>
    </li>
    <li class="two">
        <a href="#two">Two</a>
    </li>
    <li class="three mobileonly">
        <a href="#three">Three</a>

        <ul>
            <li class="one">
                <a href="#one">One</a>
            </li>
            <li class="two">
                <a href="#two">Two</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This fiddle will console.log the current clicked links href value;

http://jsfiddle.net/seemly/b5oj5au9/1/

Comment: i have made anchor id in page properly and some links are working

Comment: right... help us help you. What is/isn't working? what is the expected behaviour? Have you got an actual live code sample that is or is not working? If so, please provide it.